# UWP C++ Mouse Button Up Events Not Working Consistently

Tags: uwp, windows-10, directx

OnPointerPressed works just fine but OnPointerReleased does not.

```
window->KeyDown +=
    ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, KeyEventArgs^>(this, &EngineMain::OnKeyPressed);

window->KeyUp +=
    ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, KeyEventArgs^>(this, &EngineMain::OnKeyReleased);

window->PointerPressed +=
    ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, PointerEventArgs^>(this, &EngineMain::OnPointerPressed);

window->PointerReleased +=
    ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, PointerEventArgs^>(this, &EngineMain::OnPointerReleased);

window->PointerMoved +=
    ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, PointerEventArgs^>(this, &EngineMain::OnPointerMoved);

void EngineMain::OnPointerPressed(CoreWindow^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/rifle.wav")->StartSound();

        args->Handled = true;
    }

    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsRightButtonPressed)
    {
        m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/shotgun.wav")->StartSound();

        args->Handled = true;
    }
}

void EngineMain::OnPointerReleased(CoreWindow^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates lmb = sender->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::LeftButton);
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates mmb = sender->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::MiddleButton);
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates rmb = sender->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::RightButton);

    if (lmb == Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates::Down)
    {
        m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/rifle.wav")->StartSound();

        args->Handled = true;
    }

    if (rmb == Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates::Down)
    {
        m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/shotgun.wav")->StartSound();

        args->Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I did notice a pattern with the clicks.  It goes as follows:

Mouse down makes sound, Mouse release makes sound, Mouse down makes sound ,Mouse release no sound

and then it repeats OR

Mouse down makes sound, Mouse release makes no sound, Mouse down makes sound, Mouse release makes sound

The mouse events these days seem overwhelmingly complicated.  Any help would be appreciated or maybe even a coding example of how to setup the proper OnPointerReleased events for mouse buttons.  Keyboard events are correct.  The MSDN for the released events is a total fail as it doesn't tell you how to check the button that was released.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put the code `m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/rifle.wav")->StartSound();` in the front of the `OnPointerReleased` method, and you could view the sound plays when mouse button is released, that is, the `OnPointerReleased` method is called every time when the mouse release. I understand that you want to identify which mouse button is released on the `OnPointerReleased` method. There are two ways you could try.

One approach is to change the condition of the if statement, for example:

```
void UpEvent::MainPage::OnPointerReleased(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    args->Handled = true;

    Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates lmb = sender->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::LeftButton);
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates mmb = sender->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::MiddleButton);
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates rmb = sender->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::RightButton);

    if (lmb != Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates::None)
    {
        m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/rifle.wav")->StartSound();
    }

    if (rmb != Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates::None)
    {
        m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/shotgun.wav")->StartSound();

    }

}
```

Another approach is to get the mouse button information in OnPointerPressed method instead of in OnPointerReleased method.

```
int mouseButton=-1;

void UpEvent::MainPage::OnPointerPressed(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        ……
        mouseButton = 0;
    }
    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsRightButtonPressed)
    {
        ……
        mouseButton = 1;
    }

}

void UpEvent::MainPage::OnPointerReleased(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    args->Handled = true;

    if (mouseButton == 0)
    {
        //Left mouse button is released
         m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/rifle.wav")->StartSound();
    }
    if (mouseButton == 1)
    {
        //Right mouse button is released
         m_soundManager->GetSound(L"./Assets/shotgun.wav")->StartSound();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question and thought leaving the post would be a good idea.  You will actually need to use booleans and reset them during the OnPointerReleased because the sender and args are inaccurate.  Do it with booleans:

```
void EngineMain::OnPointerPressed(CoreWindow^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        m_mouseDevice->m_keyMap[DI::CMouseDevice::LMB]->m_isDown = true;
    }

    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsMiddleButtonPressed)
    {
        m_mouseDevice->m_keyMap[DI::CMouseDevice::MMB]->m_isDown = true;
    }

    if (args->CurrentPoint->Properties->IsRightButtonPressed)
    {
        m_mouseDevice->m_keyMap[DI::CMouseDevice::RMB]->m_isDown = true;
    }
}

void EngineMain::OnPointerReleased(CoreWindow^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    m_mouseDevice->ResetButtons();
}
```

m_mouseDevice->ResetButtons(); resets all the booleans to false.  Although this is only a one button at a time strategy, it seems to be the only way due to the inaccuracy.  One final note, the OnPointerPressed only happens once for the button pressed so do it this way if you need to handle the buttons being held down.